# under repair vs under repairing

Tags: phrase-usage

I can see the following sign around,

> The elevator is **under repair**.

Then, how about this?

> The elevator is **under repairing**.

I'd like to know subtle difference between them, if both are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"repair" can be either a noun or a verb, and "repairing" can be either a participle or a [gerund](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/01/) (a verbal noun).

"Under" is a preposition, and prepositions must be followed by a noun, so both "repair" as a noun and "repairing" as a gerund (verbal noun) are syntactically correct.

There is plenty of information about when to use a gerund rather than an infinitive, but I can't find anything about gerund versus noun, so you will have to take my word for it that in this context, with "under", the only acceptable version is

> The elevator is under repair.

I can't think of a situation where "under" + gerund doesn't sound wrong: you always use the simple noun, for example "under construction", "under sentence" and "under scrutiny".

Comment: Thanks JavaLatte. It seems to me that the point is "to use simple noun" rather. :)

Comment: And I wonder if you could let me know which one is correct @javaLatte in my sentence: **"My car needs repair / repairing**"?

Comment: @A-friend both are ok. repair is slightly more formal.

Answer (score 1):

> The elevator is <strike>under repairing</strike>.

**Don't** say that. The phrase *under repair* is a fixed phrase, and the word *repair* doesn't get conjugated in that context.

An alternative wording would be:

> The elevator is **being repaired**.

And, after the repair is complete:

> The elevator **has been repaired**.

I suppose it would be grammatical to say:

> The repair of the elevator is underway.

but that is not idiomatic, and it's much wordier than it needs to be. It sounds "grammatical but irregular."